# Issue in install climata module in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to install "climata" module in python as shown here (https://github.com/heigeo/climata) so that I can download streamflow data from usgs as shown here (https://www.earthdatascience.org/tutorials/acquire-and-visualize-usgs-hydrology-data/).

When I run the following lines of codes below, I am getting an error:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from climata.usgs import DailyValueIO
```

The error:

```
File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\climata\usgs\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from wq.io import NetLoader, TupleMapper, BaseIO

ImportError: No module named wq.io
```

I followed the steps as shown in [this](https://www.earthdatascience.org/tutorials/acquire-and-visualize-usgs-hydrology-data/) website.

Comment: Did you try `pip install wq`?

Comment: How did you install `climata`?

Comment: it works well for me if I do just `pip install climata`, it also installs dependencies of `climata`

Comment: i did pip install climata but before that  i did pip install wq. Now, its throwing me this error: from urllib.parse import urlsplit, urlencode, urlparse, parse_qs, urlunparse. ImportError: No module named parse. I have installed parse using pip install parse. But, still getting this error.